# Shopify Buy Button - How to Pass Product SKU, Name, Price & Quantity to Meta Pixel and GTM/GA4

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

After finally figuring out how to initiate the Meta(FB) Pixel and Google Tag Manager tracking codes within a Shopify Buy Button, I am now trying to figure out how to pass the Product SKU, Name, Price & Quantity without having to hard code it(especially needed when using Collection Buy Button Code).

Where do I find the list of product detail variables?

```
"DOMEvents": {
'click .shopify-buy__btn-wrapper .shopify-buy__btn': function (evt, target) {

fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
content_name: ????,
content_type: 'product',
value: ????,
quantity: ??,
currency: 'USD'
});

// Push the "add_to_cart" event data to the data layer
window.dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'add_to_cart',
  'ecommerce': {
    'add': {
      'products': [{
        'id': ?????,
        'price': ?????,
        'currencyCode': 'USD'
        
      }]
    }
  }
});  

}
},
```

I have the tried the below, but it didn't work

```
fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
content_name: ui.components.product[0].selectedVariant.sku,
content_type: 'product',
value: ui.components.product[0].selectedVariant.price,
currency: 'USD'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out some of this.

With individual Buy Buttons the following code works:

```
"DOMEvents": {
'click .shopify-buy__btn-wrapper .shopify-buy__btn': function (evt, target) {

var prod_name = ui.components.product[0].model.title; 
var prod_qty = ui.components.product[0].selectedQuantity;    
var prod_sku = ui.components.product[0].selectedVariant.sku;
var prod_price = ui.components.product[0].selectedVariant.price.amount;            
        
fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
    content_name: prod_name,
    content_id: prod_sku,
  quantity: prod_qty,        
    content_type: 'product', 
    value: prod_price,
    currency: 'USD'
});
```

I have **not** been able to get it to work with collection code yet.

Also, for some reason using "var prod_sku = ui.components.product[0].selectedVariant.title;" resulted in it passing "Default Title" instead of the actual product title.